# given a list of 5 names and scores print out the ones that were above average

Tags: python

i was creating a code that would answer the question above and i made the following

```
scores=[23,11,19,13,26]
names1=["joe","tom","bob","fred","barry"]
average=(scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2]+scores[3]+scores[4])/5
print("the average is",average,"and the following are above average:")
if scores[0] > average:
    print(names[0],scores[0])
if scores[1] > average:
    print(names[1],scores[1])
if scores[2] > average:
    print(names[2],scores[2])
if scores[3] > average:
    print(names[3],scores[3])
if scores[4] > average:
    print(names[4],scores[4])
```

however for an unknown reason to me it displayed IndexError: list index out of range

i am not sure how i can solve this error?

Comment: Your list of names is called `names1` instead of `names`. Maybe you have a shorter names list still hanging around... Anyway, rename it to  `names` and your code works fine.

Comment: I would vote to close as a typo, but the failure to use loops is just too glaring to overlook.

Answer (score 2):

You should *loop* over the pairs of names and scores, printing a line for each score that is above average. Note the built-in function `sum` loops over the scores internally.

```
scores = [...]
names1 = [...]
average = sum(scores)/5
print("The average is {} and the following are above average".format(average))
for name, score in zip(names1, scores):
    if score > average:
        print(name, score)
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you have a typo, your list is called names1, not names, so I would change that. Your code will work if you do that, but you can make it better by using a `for` loop.

This should work:

```
scores=[23,11,19,13,26]
names=["joe","tom","bob","fred","barry"]
average=(scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2]+scores[3]+scores[4])/5
print("the average is",average,"and the following are above average:")
for i in range(len(scores)):
    if scores[i] > average:
        print(names[i],scores[i])
```